# Rest api return 401 code when calling it with oidc token

Tags: reactjs, rest, fetch, openid-connect

I have a problem where the REST api return 401 sometimes. When I log in it works perfectly but after one hour or something like that it stops working, and I constantly gget error 401, no matter if I add the token to the request. I am using OIDC with ReactJs.

```
fetch('api/favorites/filter-listing', {
      method: 'post',
      headers: {
             'Authorization': !token ? '' : `Bearer ${token}`,
             'Accept': 'application/json',
             'Content-Type': 'application/json'
       },
       body: JSON.stringify(this.state.filters)
 })
```

I have already verified that my token is not null when i pass it into the fetch call.

I get this response:

```
POST https://localhost:44335/api/favorites/fav-ids net::ERR_ABORTED 401
```

Comment: Your token probably expired and you need to get a new one.

Comment: @Evert I have checked it and yes, it is expired. How can I get a new access token using oidc usermanager? I have tried using revokeAccessToken method but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: OpenID is just OAuth2 with extra cruft. If you're using some kind of library, you should be looking for a 'refresh_token' operation.

Comment: You _might_ like my library that wraps around fetch and adds OAuth2 and refreshing, but it's hard to tell if this integrates well with what you use today: https://www.npmjs.com/package/fetch-mw-oauth2